# Byte array for guid must be exactly 16 bytes long

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to insert Guid into my Asp.net project as a unique identifier. We have defined the table column length to 16. When I insert Data I get an exception: `Data is too long` - but when I increase the column length, it changes to `byte array for guid must be exactly 16 bytes long`.

I have tried adding Data thru NHibernate. The database server is MySQL, column data type is `:- BINARY` and length is `:- 16`

```
public class Myapp

public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

We write code for getting Data from Cs page:

```
Myapp.Id =Guid.NewGuid();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: OK, the length is 16. But what is the Type?

Comment: What are you trying to insert the Guid into? If you are trying to insert it into a database what database and what does the statement look like?

Comment: Use `Guid` on the ASP.NET side and `uniqueidentifier` on the DB side. There's no byte arrays or fields with length anywhere. Assuming you're using MS SQL, that is.

Comment: Is the Column of type `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: We are using My sql and column type is binary.
length is 16.

Comment: we try to add Data thru NHibernate and Data base server is MySQL.

public class Myapp

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

We write code for getting Data from Cs page

  Myapp.Id =Guid.NewGuid();

Comment: Does it work as expected if you don't use NHibernate? Try to call `.ToByeArray()` as well.

Comment: Don't add clarifications in comments, _edit_ the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server there is a type for a `Guid` value `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: We are using mySql data base. if i change data type so we makes very big changes in Code because we are using Nhibarnet ORM andwe have very long project so we can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use a Column with `Char(16)`in your MySQL Database

Comment: We are using mySql data base. if i change data type so we makes very big changes in Code because we are using Nhibarnet ORM and we have very long project so we can't change it.

plz give some alternative solutions.

Comment: CHAR(16) is the best way to store a Guid in Database because it is 16 Bytes Long and so you can Transfer your data to any SQL Server available. But i have to respect that you are in a running Project. I dont know any better solution.